# How to install iOS app on a real device for iOS Test Automation?

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest, ios-ui-automation, xcuitest

I am writing XCUITests for an app without source code. I have .app file of the app.
I am using `XCUIApplication`s `init(bundleIdentifier:)` method to launch the application.
This works fine if I have the app pre installed on the device.
If I don't have the app insalled, `XCUIApplication` fails to launch the app as it cannot find the build.
How can I provide .app file of the app to Xcode to install and launch the application using `init(bundleIdentifier:)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually done with https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ideviceinstaller

This tool allows installing and uninstalling the apps